# Updating boolean attr with ? before it is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Message` model that has a boolean `from_posting?` attribute that defaults to `false`.

In some cases, I want to set this attr to `true` before the Message is saved.

```
def create
  @message = current_user.sent_messages.build(message_params)
    if params[:reply] == 'true'
      @message.from_posting? = true
    end
    if @message.save
      render json: @message, status: 200, serializer: MessageSerializer
    else
      render json: @message.errors, status: 400
    end
 end
```

But `@message.from_posting? = true` throws an `unexpected =` error. I can do `@message.title ='something'`, but why can't I use `attr_accessor` to set the boolean value when the attr ends in a `?`?

I thought about saving the record and then updating `from_posting?` if I need to, but that just seems like an extra db write. I tried using `@posting.toggle(from_posting?)` but that throws an error on `from_posting?` as well.

Comment: Is the attribute name from_posting or from_posting?, generally you should name the attribute from_posting not ending with a question mark.

Comment: It's from_posting? with the question mark. I thought it was best practice to name boolean attr with question marks?

Comment: Nope the best practice is to end methods returning booleans with question marks which is by the way is automatically added by rails. So if you have a boolean field called from_posting (without the trailing question mark), rails will add the helper of from_posting? which is a method you can use (try it in the console).

Comment: it's fine to use a question mark in method names that return true or false, but I would not use a question mark in an attribute name.

Comment: cheers, this is going to be an awful refactor as I've got a bunch of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly suggest the refactor suggested in the comments. Renaming the from_posting? field to from_posting is the correct course of action.

If a refactor is not possible, you **should** be able to use:

```
send('from_posting?=', true)
```

or

```
write_attribute('from_posting?', true)
```

or

```
@message['from_posting?'] = true
```

The last option is an alias of the second.

David Verhasselt has an excellent writeup of different ways for setting ActiveRecord attributes [here](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/).

Comment: cheers, yeah the refactor won't be too bad because of the helper that adds the `?` method. I was mostly concerned about refactoring the angular side because that uses the `?` attrs all over